# Tensorflow ResourceExhausted Error OOM when allocating tensor with shape [] using GPU

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to train a VGG-style CNN on tensorflow and my input size is:
 **2 batchsize * 1080 hight *1920 wide * 5 channel** and my network structure is:

1. Conv 3*3*64
2. Conv 3*3*128
3. Maxpooling 3*3 stride 3
4. Conv 3*3*256
5. And a COnv with 1*1*256*2 outputs

Everything runs OK on CPU version, But has error using GPU:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2,128,1080,1920]
 [[Node: Feature_Map/Conv2 = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Feature_Map/Act1, Feature_Map/Variable_2/read)]]
```

Seems it gets stuck on the second layer. my GPU is **GTX1060**(6G) on Spyder (windows). I have added the following command to allow GPU memory growth using:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks very much

Comment: You are allocating 2GB tensor and running out of GPU memory. When running on CPU it uses main memory and doesn't run out.

Comment: But I got 6GB on my GPU. Why 2G makes it out of the memory?

Comment: It tried to allocate 2GB tensor when there was less than 2GB memory available. I would guess space was used up by activations from other layers

Comment: I solved that problem by the following steps: 1. Resize the image size smaller 2. Using **tf.recorder** to reduce the memory cunsumption

Comment: And thank you for the help! @ Yaroslav